# Generate boilerplate code based on classes in another project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sourcegenerators

I have a visual studio solution with a couple of C# projects. One of them contains my domain classes and has no infrastructure dependencies and another contains classes that depend on various 3rd party libraries, it's what you'd call an infrastructure project.

For each class in my domain project I have to write a corresponding class in my infrastructure project which contains just some boilerplate code required for using a feature of one of the 3rd party dependencies so I'd like to generate that automatically whenever my domain class is changed.

I was able to generate the classes containing this boilerplate code by creating a [source generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) with a `ISyntaxReceiver` that adds the abstract syntax tree of my domain classes for which I need to generate the boilerplate code to a list which is then used by my source generator to create the required classes. I then added this source generator as a project reference to my domain project but I have a problem: the infrastructure classes I need to generate inherit from a class of a 3rd party dependency so I have to add that 3rd party dependency to my domain project.

What I tried to do was to add my source generator as a project reference to my infrastructure project (which already references the 3rd party dependency, and also my domain project) but the source generator does not run because the `ISyntaxReceiver`'s `OnVisitSyntaxNode` method does not get called for any of the classes in the referenced domain project.

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a source generator that generates code based on classes in projects referenced by the project that references that source generator?

I am aware of the AnalyzerAdditionalFiles, but seems like that should be used for making generation decisions based on more than just C# code